# React native app crashing android 13 production but fine on other versions

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, compiler-errors, mobile-development

I have created a React Native application, and it works smoothly on all versions except Android 13. I have tried the solutions I found on other StackOverflow posts, but haven't achieved any results. My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "aloha-live",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant=productiondebug --appId com.alohachat && npx react-native start && emulator -avd emulator-5554 && adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios ",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "ios:beta": "react-native run-ios --scheme 'AlohaLiveStaging'  --configuration 'StagingDebug'",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --ext src/*/.{js,ts,tsx}",
    "clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-* && ./gradlew --stop && cd .. && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&  yarn cache clean && yarn install && cd ios && rm -rf Podfile.lock && rm -rf Pods/ && pod install && cd .. && yarn start --reset-cache",
    "metro-clean": "watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&  yarn cache clean && yarn start --reset-cache",
    "cache-clean": "yarn start --reset-cache",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "prettier:write": "yarn prettier --write src/*/.{js,ts,tsx,json}",
    "package-check": "npm-check -i @aloha/* -p",
    "package-check:dev": "npm-check -i @aloha/* -d",
    "build-android:apk": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-* && ./gradlew --stop && watchman watch-del-all && ./gradlew assembleProductionRelease && ./gradlew --stop",
    "build-android-market": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleProductionRelease"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "1.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.17",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.3",
    "@rnhooks/keyboard": "^1.1.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.15.2",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "axios": "1.3.4",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.12",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "5.1.1",
    "false": "^0.0.4",
    "i18next": "22.4.13",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "12.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
    "react-native-adjust": "4.33.0",
    "react-native-agora": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "4.5.3",
    "react-native-code-push": "7.0.5",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.70.7",
    "react-native-config": "1.5.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "10.5.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.6.3",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "0.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "10.0.1",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.22",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-localize": "2.2.6",
    "react-native-mmkv": "2.5.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "14.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "3.8.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "5.13.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-store-review": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.10.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "3.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.2.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.5.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.5",
    "redux": "4.2.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1",
    "socket.io-client": "4.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@sentry/types": "^7.45.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.6",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.0",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.41.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.41.0",
    "@ui-kitten/metro-config": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "0.4.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "expo": {
    "autolinking": {
      "exclude": [
        "react-native-reanimated"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and my android/app/build.gradle file is as follows:

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    productiondebug: ".env.production",
    productionrelease: ".env.production",
    developmentrelease: ".env.development",
    developmentdebug: ".env.development",
    stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
    stagingdebug: ".env.staging",
]


apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"



import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call react-native bundle with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle" line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/*", "ios/*"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/sentry.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. Date.toLocaleString and String.localeCompare that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
 
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project?.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    // compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.0"

//     aarMetadata {
//     artifactId = "my-application"
//     groupId = "com.example"
//     version = "1.0"
// }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alohachat"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 106
        versionName "5.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.alohachat"
        resValue 'string', "CODE_PUSH_APK_BUILD_TIME", String.format("\"%d\"", System.currentTimeMillis())
        
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
        }
        //react-native-image-crop-picker
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
        //react-native-iap
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the CMake build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)
            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureCMakeDebug* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732

            configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.

        //     minifyEnabled true
        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            // minifyEnabled true
            
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"

            /* Add the firebaseCrashlytics extension (by default,
                        * it's disabled to improve build speeds) and set
                        * nativeSymbolUploadEnabled to true along with a pointer to native libs. */

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir 'build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib'
            }
        }
    }

     flavorDimensions "default"
        productFlavors {
            production {
                resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '""'
                resValue 'string', 'deep_link_url', 'app.alohalive.online'
                resValue 'string', 'deep_link_scheme', 'alohalive'
            }
            staging {
                applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
                resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"TzWaC1KOII946zujOXUsbV_9VQtbq19XVGads"'
                resValue 'string', 'deep_link_url', 'app.alohalive.online'
                resValue 'string', 'deep_link_scheme', 'alohalive'
            }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0"
    
  
    //play store billing
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'

    //adjust
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
    implementation project(':react-native-config')


    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                                .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                                .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}


// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set newArchEnabled to true inside the gradle.properties file
    // - Invoke gradle with -newArchEnabled=true
    // - Set an environment variable ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

I tested the APK I created on Android 13, but the application is throwing an error. It displays a message to the user stating that there is an issue with the application

Is there anyone who knows what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **android:exported="true"** to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Here's an example of how you might add the **android:exported="true"** attribute to an activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
  android:name=".YourActivity"
  android:exported="true">
  <!-- other activity attributes -->
</activity>
```